# How to parse and display rss feed using Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, rss

How to parse RSS feed and display as html using Nodejs?

Answer (score 1):

I created [node-feedparser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-feedparser), and I think it works great!

```
npm install feedparser
```

Answer (score -2):

You should give a try to [node-rss](https://github.com/dylang/node-rss)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But this npm for create RSS feed But I need to  parse the rss feed and display it as html